# Inserting new values to cell array[MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

**[EDIT]**

Say, I have a cell array `A` consisting of `n` cells and each of them is a zero vector of size `(m,1)`.

> Example:     A is a 1x2 cell array    A =     [100x1 double]  [100x1
>   double]

How can I insert new values to each cells, on the same rows and at the same time without having to write separate lines of code? Can I use `cellfun` to do so?

For instance, how can I replace the `ith`row of the first cell with the new value `m` and  the `ith`row of the second cell with the new value `n`, using a single line of code?

`m` and `n` may or may not be the same values.

Comment: I don't understand, are the cell contents always vectors, Mx1, or are they matrices, MxN? Also, in your question, do you want to assign `m` to one cell and `n` to the other one, or two separate columns in row `i`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are you trying to replace existing rows, add new rows in the middle of each vector, or something else?

Comment: @Trogdor I will make the clarifications

Comment: @beaker Let me clarify things in the main question space.

Comment: @nashynash That would be the place to do it. And now that I've seen your previous question, I have to ask why you've chosen not to use a multidimensional array rather than a cell array (assuming the matrices are all the same size, of course).

Comment: @beaker My choice for using a cell array, which I though was easier, was to split a 2D matrix into smaller matrices. Yes, the smaller matrices are of the same sizes.

Comment: What's easier than `A(row_to_change, :) = [newval1, newval2]`? I think you need to consider using normal matrices.

Comment: @beaker Yes, that is true. Guess, I really did not consider everything when I chose cell array, although it has served me some good purpose. Notwithstanding the overlooking, I will leave the question open as it might help someone in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

as in comments noted you may try other options such as array for its efficiency, however as an answer to the question you can use evalin function  and using change_cell you can for example change contents of second row fo each cell to the vals just in one line of code!:

```
A = {[1 2 3],[4 5 6]};
change_cell = @(rownum , vals) evalin(...
                                    'base', ...
                                    [...
                                        'rownum =', int2str(rownum),';',...
                                        'vals=[', num2str(vals),'];',...
                                        'for i = 1:length(A);',...
                                            'A{i}(rownum)=vals(i);',...
                                        'end;'...
                                    ]);
change_cell(2, [6 8])
```